# Translating floor plan position into coordinates on screen map

Tags: android, maps, coordinate-systems, indoor-positioning-system

I have a custom floor plan in an ImageView and I am trying to determine how to translate a position on the floor plan into screen coordinates.

Is there a recommended way to go about implementing this as I'm not sure how to proceed. I am not using the Maps API, just a custom floor plan I created myself.

Comment: sure,  use getImageMatrix()

Comment: have you accomplished this purposes @OsborneCox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
screenCoordX = (imageCoordX / imageWidth) * screenWidth;
screenCoordY = (imageCoordY / imageHeight) * screenHeight;
```

Make sure all the values are floats / doubles.

This should get you started.

Comment: What unit are using for imageCoord? px? Would the screenWidth and screenHeight be in px or dp? Apologies if my questions seem silly but I'm a little bit confused with this.

Comment: Either all the values are in dp, or all the values are in px. As long as it's consistent, it shouldnt matter. Give it a try, let me know if there are any issues.